# Prettier wrongly formatting document quickly then correcting

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Since last Monday, my prettier plugin with VSCode is giving me strange behavior which is very annoying and I cannot find the root cause of it.

As soon as I hit CMD + S I have two possible outcome :

1. The document goes to an unwanted format briefly and the comes back to normal
2. The document goes to an unwanted format and I have to again hit CMD + S to correct it

Here's a small .gif to explain the situation.

[image: Result of my prettier]

My prettier version :

package.json : `"prettier": "^1.19.1"`
vscode plugin : `3.8.0`

My .eslintrc.json :

```
{
    "extends": ["airbnb-base", "plugin:prettier/recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["warn", "never"],
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
            "error",
            {
                "devDependencies": true
            }
        ],
        "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
        "no-restricted-syntax": 0,
        "no-await-in-loop": 0,
        "object-curly-newline": 0,
        "no-constant-condition": 2,
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
            1,
            {
                "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
            }
        ],
        "react/state-in-constructor": [2, "never"],
        "no-mixed-operators": 0,
        "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
        "react/no-unused-prop-types": 2,
        "jsx-a11y/media-has-caption": 0,
        "no-console": ["error", { "allow": ["warn", "error"] }],
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "no-global-assign": 0,
        "prefer-const": [
            "error",
            {
                "destructuring": "any",
                "ignoreReadBeforeAssign": false
            }
        ],
        "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
        "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
        "max-lines": [
            "error",
            {
                "max": 500,
                "skipBlankLines": true,
                "skipComments": true
            }
        ],
        "max-len": [
            "error",
            100,
            {
                "ignoreComments": true,
                "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true,
                "ignoreStrings": true
            }
        ],
        "curly": 0,
        "consistent-return": 0,
        "arrow-parens": 0,
        "react/no-array-index-key": 0,
        "no-return-assign": 0,
        "comma-dangle": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": "off",
        "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0,
        "no-multi-str": 0,
        "newline-before-return": 2,
        "newline-after-var": 2,
        "newline-per-chained-call": 2,
        "import/newline-after-import": 2,
        "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0,
        "react/require-default-props": 0
    },
    "plugins": ["prettier"]
}
```